# Set final Rect dimensions at initialization

Tags: android

I would like to setup a `Rect` as being final and set it's `.top` `.left` etc and only read from it.
Is it possible to set the dimensions at initialization?

```
public static final Rect myRect = new Rect();
```

Comment: Not sure about this but could you initialize using the constructor like so: `new Rect(left,top,right,bottom);` -- As per the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html

Comment: ah! thanks! Didnt realize it had a constructor for the values. please make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments it is done by using the alternate constructors:

```
public static final Rect myRect = new Rect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
```

[See documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html)